# Create adjacency matrix from char[][] array provided rules

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I want to change a `char[][]` array (lets call it `cA`) into an adjacency matrix. An adjacency matrix has columns and rows equal to the number of elements in an array, and each vertex in the adjacency matrix is either `true` or `false` depending if the elements in the initial array are adjacent. I want to bend the rules a little and also constrain an adjacency matrix vertex to true iff the elements are adjacent **and** one of the elements is not a specific value.

Here's what `cA` array looks like:

```
z y z
z z z
z y y
```

The adjacency matrix (lets call it `aM`) for the `cA` array will be an `int` array of size `[3*3][3*3]`. The conditions for `aM(i,j)` to be `true` are that the elements `i` and `j` in `cA` array must be adjacent, but neither `i` or `j` can be "y".

Lets number the `cA` array elements 1 through 9.

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

`aM` can be described by doing the below operations:

```
aM(1,1) //false, no self-adjacency
aM(1,2) //false, 2 is a "y"
aM(1,3) //false, 1 is not adjacent to 3
aM(1,4) //true, 1 is adjacent to 4, neither are "y"
aM(1,5) //false, 1 is not adjacent to 5
aM(1,6) //false, 1 is not adjacent to 6
aM(1,7) through aM(1,9) //false, there is no adjacency between 1 and 7, 8, or 9
aM(2,1) through aM(2,9) //false, 2 is a "y"
...
```

Hopefully you get the idea. From the above, the adjacency matrix for `cA` is as below:

```
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 (i)
 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 3 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
 4 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
 5 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
 6 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
 7 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
(j)
```

The rule being `aM(i,j) == 1` iff `i != j`, `i != "y" && j != "y"`, and both `i` and `j` are adjacent to each other.

I'm having difficulty concocting an algorithm to create an adjacency matrix provided a `char[][]` array. I've defined the rules, but finding constraints for iteration is problematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
static void set(boolean[][] aM, int cols, int row0, int col0, int row1, int col1) {
    int index0 = row0 * cols + col0;
    int index1 = row1 * cols + col1;
    aM[index0][index1] = aM[index1][index0] = true;
}

static boolean[][] adjacencyMatrix(char[][] cA) {
    int rows = cA.length;
    int cols = cA[0].length;
    boolean[][] aM = new boolean[rows * cols][rows * cols];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
            if (cA[i][j] == 'y')
                continue;
            if (i + 1 < rows && cA[i + 1][j] != 'y')
                set(aM, cols, i, j, i + 1, j);
            if (j + 1 < cols && cA[i][j + 1] != 'y')
                set(aM, cols, i, j, i, j + 1);
        }
    }
    return aM;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[][] cA = {
        {'z', 'y', 'z'},
        {'z', 'z', 'z'},
        {'z', 'y', 'y'},
    };
    boolean[][] aM = adjacencyMatrix(cA);
    for (boolean[] row : aM) {
        for (boolean cell : row)
            System.out.print(cell ? "1" : "0");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
000100000
000000000
000001000
100010100
000101000
001010000
000100000
000000000
000000000
```

Comment: Wonderful, this works excellently. I've noticed that all adjacency matrices are symmetric along the diagonal, and the diagonal is always `{0}` (unless self-adjacency is possible, then it's `{1}`). Would it be more efficient to only compute `aM(i,j)` for the upper triangular matrix and then just copy to the lower triangular matrix? `aM(i,j)` always equals `aM(j,i)`.

Comment: See the line 4 of my code (`aM[index0][index1] = aM[index1][index0] = true;`).  This algorithm calculates only one way adjacency.  And the result is stored in two places `aM(i, j)` and `aM(j, i)`.  If you change the result matrix to triangular, you can save memory but not save time.